# inner product (Bra - Ket) involving projection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics, projection-matrices, quantum-computation

In quantum mechanics, the action of a projection operator $\hat{P}$ acting on a quantum mechanical system, prepared in a state $| \psi \rangle$, is described by the eigenvector equation

$\hat{P} | \psi \rangle = c | \psi \rangle $ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

How can I show that $trace(|\psi\rangle \langle \psi | \hat{P}) = \langle \psi | \hat{P} | \psi \rangle $?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property

Comment: Note that in the link whpowell96 gives, the $A,B,C,D$ are all finite dimensional matrices, thought not necessarily square. However, their dimensions must be such that the pairwise products $AB, BC, CD, DA$ are all defined. In your case $|\psi\rangle$ is a vector in some Hilbert space $V$, which may be identified with the linear map $\Bbb C \to V : c \mapsto c|\psi\rangle$, $\langle \psi|$ may identified with the linear map $V\to\Bbb C : |\phi\rangle \mapsto \langle \psi|\phi\rangle$, and $\hat P : V \to V$ is linear as well.

Comment: $V$ may be infinite-dimensional, but all three operators are trace-class ($\hat P$ is a projection operator and the other two are trivially trace-class), so the trace is well-defined, and the proof of the cyclic property on finite-dimensional matrices generalizes to infinite dimensions

Comment: Or, if $|\psi\rangle$ is actually meant to be an eigenvector of $\hat P$, there is an easy proof, as the only eigenvalues of a projection operator are $0$ and $1$, If the eigenvalue of $|\psi\rangle$ is $1$, then $\langle\psi|\hat P = \langle\psi|$. And if the eigenvalue of $|\psi\rangle$ is $0$, then $\langle\psi|\hat P = 0$.

Comment: You could use the [definition of the trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Generalizations) of trace-class operators.

Comment: I.e., if $\hat{P}$ is [trace-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class), the trace of $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\hat{P}$ [is given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Generalizations) $\sum_n\langle e_n|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\hat{P}|e_n\rangle$ for some orthonormal basis $(e_n)$, and choosing $e_1=\psi$ the result follows.